# Ruby Singleton methods for class and objects

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby Singletons and i found some ways to define and get list of Class and Object singleton methods.

#### Class Singleton Methods

Ways to define **class singleton methods:**

```
class MyClass

  def MyClass.first_sing_method
    'first'
  end

  def self.second_sing_method
    'second'
  end

  class << self
    def third_sing_method
      'third'
    end
  end

  class << MyClass
    def fourth_sing_method
      'fourth'
    end
  end
end

def MyClass.fifth_sing_method
  'fifth'
end

MyClass.define_singleton_method(:sixth_sing_method) do
  'sixth'
end
```

Ways to get list of **class singletons methods:**

```
#get singleton methods list for class and it's ancestors 
MyClass.singleton_methods

#get singleton methods list for current class only  
MyClass.methods(false)
```

#### Object Singleton Methods

Ways to define **object singleton methods**

```
class MyClass
end

obj = MyClass.new

class << obj
  def first_sing_method
    'first'
  end
end

def obj.second_sing_method
  'second'
end

obj.define_singleton_method(:third_sing_method) do
  'third'
end
```

Way to get list of **object singleton methods**

```
#get singleton methods list for object and it's ancestors  
obj.singleton_methods

#get singleton methods list for current object only
obj.methods(false)
```

***Are there other ways to do this?***

Comment: Even though this question has been answered long ago, for completeness: you can also use methods class_eval and instance_eval. For instance: obj.instance_eval {def hi;puts "hi";end}, or Object.class_eval {def self.foo;puts "foo";end} (this is just the same as extending via open classes), or as last: Object.instance_eval{def bar;puts "bar";end} (this opens the virtual class of Object. Even though self is the same as the previous,it still is in a different environment!)

Comment: Nice sum up, should be a wiki

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the way to list singleton methods is with `singleton_methods`. The `methods` method returns a list of the names of public and protected methods of the object. Also, it is defined in the [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) class. Try `extend`ing an instance. It is one of the most elegant ways, as it supports code reuse and seems to me very object-oriented:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "Hi"
  end
end

module Bar
  def foo
    puts "Bye"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar
#=> hi

f.extend Bar
f.foo
#=> bye

f.methods(false)
#=> []
# the module we extended from is not a superclass
# therefore, this must be empty, as expected

f.singleton_methods
#=> ["foo"]
# this lists the singleton method correctly

g = Foo.new
g.foo
#=> NoMethodError
```

**Edit**: In the comment you asked why `methods(false)` returns nothing in this case. After reading through the C code it seems that:

- `methods` returns all the methods available for the object (also the ones in included modules)
- `singleton_methods` returns all the singleton methods for the object (also the ones in included modules) ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001026))
- `singleton_methods(false)` returns all the singleton methods for the object, but **not** those declared in included modules
- `methods(false)` supposedly returns the singleton methods by calling `singleton_methods`, **but** it also passes the parameter `false` to it; whether this is a bug or a feature - I do not know

Hopefully, this clarifies the issue a little. Bottom line: call `singleton_methods`, seems more reliable.

Comment: Thank you, nice feature, i didn't know about it. But why `methods(false)` don't show added method?

Comment: I can also extend `class` this way

Comment: I experimented with `methods(false)` and concluded that `method(false)` show only own object's methods, it not show methods from upper classes in ancestor chain

Comment: at previous deleted comment you said that `methods()` is alias for `instance_methods()`, is it true? In this case how `instance_methods()` can return singleton methods? Singleton and instance methods are different.

Comment: sorry for a lot of questions, but i try to understand

Comment: I withdraw what I said about the alias, it is not. The method seems to be undocumented (see the edited answer). It seems, as you said, that it only goes through the class hierarchy. So, not the included modules, as they are not part of it.

Comment: I experimented this that, and got such results: `methods()` return list of all publicly accessibly methods of receiver; `methods(false)` return singletons methods of current object/class (without superclasses methods)

Answer (score 6):

Some more ways:

**Class singleton methods**

```
class << MyClass
  define_method :sixth_sing_method do
    puts "sixth"
  end
end

class MyClass
  class << self
    define_method :fourth_sing_method do
      puts "seventh"
    end
  end
end
```

**Object singleton methods**

```
class << obj
  define_method :fourth_sing_method do
    puts "fourth"
  end
end
```

Next, you can use `define_method` and `define_singleton_method` in combination with `send`, e.g.

```
obj.send :define_singleton_method, :nth_sing_method, lambda{ puts "nth" }
```

and all possible combinations thereof. To use `define_method`, you need to capture the singleton class first as in this (the same works for class objects, too)

```
singleton_class = class << obj; self end
singleton_class.send :define_method, :nth_sing_method, lambda{ puts "nth" }
```

Another ways is using `class_eval` on the singleton class objects:

```
singleton_class.class_eval do
  def nth_sing_method
    puts "nth"
  end
end
```

And then you once again may combine `send` with `class_eval`...

There are myriads of ways, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Object singleton methods

instance_eval

```
class A
end

a = A.new

a.instance_eval do
def v 
"asd"
end
end

 a.singleton_methods
 => [:z, :v]
```