# How "self" works inside an Enumerable block inside a method

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand how the `self` keyword is working in the following sample:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :field
  def without_self
    [1,2,3].each { |x| field = x }
  end
  def with_self
    [1,2,3].each { |x| self.field = x }
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.without_self
t.field # => nil
t.with_self
t.field # => 3
```

I am trying to fit this behavior into my larger understanding of the rules for how "self" works.  Please correct any mistakes in the following, or add any clarifications or simplifications:

1. Inside a method (but not inside a block/proc/lambda within that method), "self" is implied to be the object on which the method is defined, and thus adding it explicitly in front of another method you are calling never changes the behavior.
2. Adding "self" in front of a method *definition* turns that method into a class method.  Should I understand this as its own rule or as a special case of Rule 1 above?  That is, are they both application of a more general rule about how self is interpreted at parse time?  Inside a class, self refers to the class object and inside a method self refers to that method's owning object?
3. Why does the interpretation of self change the behavior inside a block, as in my example code?  Is the rule something like this: blocks have their own local scope, which is the default, but if you add "self" explicitly ruby assumes you mean that block's parent object, since a block has no concept of "self" otherwise?
4. In all cases, are the rules surrounding "self" and its interpretation parse time rules?

Comment: Without a receiver, `field = x` sets a variable, `self.field = x` invokes the setter method generated by `attr_accessor`. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods

Comment: To mix some syntax sugar you might use `@field` instead for `self.field` to refer instance variables.

Comment: @mudasobwa nitpicking, but `@field` is not syntactic sugar for `self.field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad. 2 Yes, inside a class, `self` refers to class object and that's why `def self.method_name` defines class method. It is a special case of [singleton method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759777/ruby-singleton-methods-for-class-and-objects).

Ad. 3 No, it doesn't have anything to do with block. It's only if you write `field = x`, Ruby treats it as local variable assignment. That's why if you call setter methods, [you should specify reciever explicitly](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/use-self-explicitly/), even if it's `self`.

Answer (score 1):

```
read_attribute
```

In the above example it doesn't matter whether self is used within a method body or block body, but if we just want to read the value of any attribute in a class, then we don't need to put self before method.

```
write_attribute or update_attribute
```

But if we want to write or update any attribute then self before that attribute is a must.